# Devise attributes for i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, devise

How can I translate the attributes of Devise's models? E.g. `session.email` or `session.remember_me`.

Both hierarchies

```
de:
  devise:
    sessions:
      email: "E-Mail"
```

and

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      session:
        email: "E-Mail"
```

do not work. What is the right identifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon the solution by myself: I have to define the model names in the namespace of simple_form as described here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form (bottom).

Answer (score 0):

The Devise I18n config files are for flash messages and subject titles to emails. You need to generate the views and modify them accordingly with:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Comment: True. But that does not give access to the model's internal attributes. E.g. `<%= f.input :password =>` still prints "Password:" instead of the German "Passwort:".

Comment: That's when you do `f.label :password, 'Passwort'`.

Comment: True. But I have error messages that auto fill the name of the attribute. So I need to translate the attributes' names like I do with all other models and their attribute, too.