# Devise custom messages when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise as authentication engine in my app.
Is there any way to use custom messages when devise validation fails.
Devise provides me with the following message when the password is blank: `Password can't be blank`, but i need another message. How can i do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ActiveRecord en.yml is the answer I would suggest if you want to change the Validation Message for Devise

Here is how the en.yml should look like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "Please Specify an Email id"
              taken: "Please use a different Email id"
              invalid: "Please Specify a valid Email id"
            password:
              blank: "Please Specify a Password"
              confirmation: "Password does not match"
            password_confirmation:
              blank: "Please Specify a Password Confirmation"
            first_name:
              blank: "Please Specify First Name"
            last_name:
              blank: "Please Specify Last Name"
        pdf:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please Specify name to PDF"
              taken: "Please use different name for PDF"
            attachment:
              blank: "Please Upload a PDF Attachment"
        data_element:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please give Element a desired name"
              taken: "Already Created Element with given name"
            color:
              blank: "Please assign a color to Element"
        template:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please Specify a Name"
              taken: "Please use a different name"
```

I advice you to define this way instead of customizing devise validation module

Because if you follow the above approach, it would be possible that you would skip a validation a place or two

for Example I the remove the above devise validation module and then substitue your own in 
User Model

then all the validation would work for but you would miss the validation in Change Password

There by resulting your to login even though the password was never supplied and never given

Keep a loop of that too

Cheer

Regards

Comment: WHERE is this? `config/locals/en.yml`?

Comment: What do you mean by getting rid of the "above devise validation module" and subsstitute your own in the User Model? First, there is no above devise validation module. What you wrote above is the en.yml file, not the devise.en.yml file. And even the devise.en.yml file isn't a validation module. How can you put the devise.en.yml code into the User model? That's like a square peg into a round hole. 

What do you mean by "keep a loop of that too"? That it will go into an infinite loop if the "change password" validation is skipped?

Comment: Another question: I thought this yml messages were messages, not actual validations. Why would changing them bypass a validation? Maybe my suggested edits are not what you meant, but it was not clear before anyway.

Comment: @gwho wow way too many question firstly @gwko the devise validation module I'm talking about is [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) and the reason I suggested that because their were answer suggesting the OP to remove devise validation module and add their custom rails validation at first even I followed the same approach but then  I found I missed the change password validation, hence the suggestion use to `.yml` instead of removing devise validation module and write your own validation

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the URL below.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise?view=asciicast

If the user is signing in, you can edit all the error messages in `devise.en.yml` under `config/locales`.

If you're signing up, Devise provides its own validations out of the box without any customizing. If you want to customize it, you can edit the `User` model.

Find  `devise :validatable` and remove the `:validatable` option. After which, you should be able to use the usual rails validations. Note that this will cause you to have to do all the validations yourself.

`validates_presence_of :password, :message=>"Your custom error message!"`

Some usual validations:

```
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but this sounds like it should be solvable with I18n, either with the devise-internal keys, or by overriding active record's validation error messages for your user model.

Here's a similar question: [Devise attributes for i18n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543594/devise-attributes-for-i18n)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your devise messages from config/locales/devise.en.yml but if you want to change to validation message then delete :validatable from Model. Then you can change a validation message like before.
For example:

```
validates_uniqueness_of    :email,     :case_sensitive => false, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
validates_format_of    :email,    :with  => Devise.email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?

validates_presence_of    :password, :on=>:create
validates_confirmation_of    :password, :on=>:create
validates_length_of    :password, :within => Devise.password_length, :allow_blank => true
```