# devise change validation message in current_password field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here goes  my code ..

```
<label>Old Password</label>
 <%= f.password_field :current_password, :class=>"myaccount_textbox" %>
<label class="error" for="current_password">
 <%= validation_errors resource.errors['current_password'] %>
</label>
...........
```

on form-submit, with wrong password, the default validation msg - **is invalid**

Requirement - need to change the *default msg*.

`devise (3.2.4)` and `rails 3.2.13` what I tried from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325176/devise-custom-messages-when-validation-fails)

in en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            current_password:
              confirmation: "Password is incorrect"
```

Currently it's not working and I get default msg only, what changes to be done, to get this fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        current_password: "Password"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            current_password:
              invalid: "is incorrect!"
```

OR

```
  devise:  
    failure:  
      invalid: 'Password is incorrect!'
```

Refer this [link](http://www.localeapp.com/projects/377) to choose the correct option for showing password incorrect message for Devise.

Comment: in the first option, you may actually want to show the full message as "Password is incorrect!", in which case you'd add the `%{attribute}` key to the message: `invalid: "%{attribute} is incorrect!"`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
# config/locales/en.yml
    en:
     activerecord:
     attributes:
     user:
         current_password: "Password"
      errors:
        models:
         user:
         attributes:
          current_password:
          confirmation: "is incorrect"
```