# Customize blank errors in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, devise, customization

Now I get an error like this:

```
Email can't be blank
```

I can change just this part

```
can't be blank

errors:
    messages:
        blank: cannot be empty
```

But it after this shows as:

```
Email cannot be empty
```

Can I change field name too? make it like

```
E-mail_something_else cannot be empty?
```

How can I do it?

My field in the form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= t('registration.email') %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => "form-field" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after modifying the file?

Comment: Can you please past your view form

Comment: @ArslanAli yes, I did restart it

Comment: @AnantKolvankar I add a field code to my question

Comment: I need the method you have use to show error messages

Comment: @AnantKolvankar `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`

Comment: try this 
`# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "E-mail address"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "is required"`

Comment: @AnantKolvankar I can change the text, but I do not want use field name like "Email cannot be empty". I want just "E-mail cannot be empty" for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the `devise_en.yml` file:

```
en:
    errors:
        format: "%{message}"
```

The default format is "%{attribute} %{message}".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest if you want to change the Validation Message for Devise.

Here is how the en.yml should look like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "Please Specify an Email id"
              taken: "Please use a different Email id"
              invalid: "Please Specify a valid Email id"
            password:
              blank: "Please Specify a Password"
              confirmation: "Password does not match"
            password_confirmation:
              blank: "Please Specify a Password Confirmation"
            first_name:
              blank: "Please Specify First Name"
            last_name:
              blank: "Please Specify Last Name"
        pdf:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please Specify name to PDF"
              taken: "Please use different name for PDF"
            attachment:
              blank: "Please Upload a PDF Attachment"
        data_element:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please give Element a desired name"
              taken: "Already Created Element with given name"
            color:
              blank: "Please assign a color to Element"
        template:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please Specify a Name"
              taken: "Please use a different name"
```

Example => I removed the above devise validation module and then substitue your own in User Model.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Orkhan : please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325176/devise-custom-messages-when-validation-fails.

Comment: It prints: `Email Please Specify an Email id` =/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search for the label you need, for example if you search `:already_confirmed` (that is the label in the locale file), you will find that in the file:

```
lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb
```

there is this line:

```
self.errors.add(:email, :already_confirmed)
```

If you change `email` in whatever key you want.

**EDIT:**
I am searching in their github repo, so I am not user it is right, but maybe the message you need is in file:

```
lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb
```

in line 269

```
record.errors.add(key, value.present? ? error : :blank)
```

Comment: clearer than mine solution: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578028/4898937)